# PureData errors

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, ubuntu-gnome

When I run PD I get these errors:

```
priority 6 scheduling failed; running at normal priority
ALSA input error (snd_pcm_open): Device or resource busy
```

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 32 bit and pd version 0.46.7 from the official repos. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be resolved after the system is suspended and after the authentication the program works without this error. Running as root, `sudo puredata`, also resolves the issue.